# Function composition in C, I'm not sure how to pass in an argument that still needs to be calculated

Tags: c

The format for the input is a x and sequence of composite functions. eg. 42 hfgf= and the output for that one would be 2829124.

This is what I have so far, I'm not sure how to let it understand the order in which it should compute this.

Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int functionF(int x) {
    x = x * x;
    return x;
}

int functionG(int x) {
    x = x + 1;
    return x;
}

int functionH(int x) {
    x = x - 1;
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    char function;
    int result;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    scanf(" %c", &function);

    while (function != '=') {

        if (function == 'f')
            functionF(n);

        if (function == 'g')
            functionG(n);

        if (function == 'h')
            functionH(n);

        scanf("%c", &function);
    }

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you expect 2829124.

Comment: Agreed: 3115226. You'd get 2829124 if the sequence were `42 hfgf`, i.e. ((42-1)^2+1)^2

Comment: Sorry it was hfgf. @Howlium you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to functions `f()`, `g()`, and `h()` are passed "by value," not "by reference." That means that changing the value of `x` in the function does not change the value of `n` in `main()`.

Instead, your functions should return a value. For example:

```
int functionF(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Then the caller should assign the result to `n` in `main()`, like this:

```
if (function == 'f')
    n = functionF(n);
```

And by the way `42 fgfg` yields 3115226. You'd get 2829124 if the sequence were `42 hfgf`, i.e. ((42-1)^2+1)^2